# JavaFX delete datarow in tableview and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, javafx, tableview, row

I would like to delete a row in tableview but also in the
underlying SQLite Database which populate the tableview

Here I get the selectedRow

```
 public void deleteDBRow() {
    if (tableV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
        Bew selBew = tableV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(selBew.getName());

        }
     }
```

and can delete it with casual code

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = ""+selBew.getName()");
```

But I would like to delete the entry in the sqlite database also

From time to time I have rows with the same text in every column - so this way
was critical - can I use rowID to delete the selected row in sqlite?

Here one try from me to get rowid in tableview

ObservableList bewList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

```
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT rowID, Name, Date, Action, Info FROM tab1";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TestB1.db");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {

            bewList.add(new Bew(rs.getInt("rowID"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("date"),
                    rs.getString("action"), rs.getString("Info")));

          System.out.println("rs.next : " + rs.getInt("rowID") +" - " + rs.getString("date") +"  " +
                    rs.getString("action") +"  " + rs.getString("Info"));
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SQLiteDB.getData ---> Error RS");
        System.err.println("*E"+e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }


    return bewList;


String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1" +
                    "(rowID INT PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,"+
                   "DATE CHAR(15) ,"+
                    "ACTION CHAR(50) ,"+
                    "INFO CHAR(3));";

           conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
```

rowID ist always 0 - don't know why ???

edit:

Controller

ObservableList bewList = DB.getData();
    tableV.setItems(bewList);

Edit:

Maybe error in here - add data

i add 4 values - rowid missing??

```
public void add(String Name, String Date, String Action, String Info) {

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TestB2.db");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String ValStr = "\'"+Name+"\' ,\'"+Date+"\',\'"+Action+"\' ,\'"+Info+"\'";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tab1 (rowID, NAME,DATE,ACTION, INFO) VALUES ("+ValStr+")";
      //  System.out.println("Button Click add"+conn.createStatement().toString());
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); //geändert
      ObservableList<Bew> list = getData();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("DB ROW add");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Just retrieve the row id too when reading from the db and store the data in your object. Otherwise assuming there is no unique constraint for values provided by your class you won't be able to identify the correct row to delete from the table...